# Processing large amounts of files, slowed down by I/O, how to make more efficent?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, io

I've been maintaining an application for a few years ever since creator stopped working on it. This application does batch operations on a large amount of pictures such as resizing, applying text, adding a logo, etc.

Lately I've been rewriting this application in order to improve efficiency and try to fully use every capability of the system by using all the available memory and splitting the operation over multiple threads.

The previous maintainer implemented multithreading in somewhat awful ways such as doing long operations in the UI thread (rendering the stop button he made inoperable) and using a really small thread pool.

So I've been optimizing code and trying out increasing the size of the thread pool but apparently nothing improves at all, the bottleneck seems to be reading and writing to disk.

Is there a way to improve this situation?

Comment: Get an SSD? Or a few and RAID 0 them?

Comment: I did tests with an SSD and the efficiency doesn't improve at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine exactly what IO the application does at the moment. Then try to convert it to sequential access patterns. Random IO is 100x slower on magnetic disks and 10x slower on SSDs.

If it is a magnetic disk make sure that only one thread writes sequentially at a time. If you're forced to do random IO tune the optimal queue length.

Comment: each thread in the pool loads the image, processes it and then saves it, it's obvious that they all start at the same time but still end up having to wait for the disk access before starting.
I had an idea of using a read and a write buffer but I wonder, would a thread that constantly reads, one that constantly saves (ideally to a different drive) and and a pool to work on as many items in the memory improve efficiency at all?

Comment: Yes it would because it would sequentialize access to the disk (as far as that is possible with many smallish files). You don't actually need dedicated reader and writer threads. Just create one lock (or SemaphoreSlim) per physical disk and acquire it during all IOs.

Comment: interesting, I'll try to figure something based on this